# Javascript datetime object to local time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date-time object like `Sun Mar 12 2017 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`. Now I want to convert this to IST ie, `Sun Mar 12 2017 13:00:00`. How can I do this? Is there an built way in Javascript to do these conversions?

Comment: what about cutting the last 13 chars with string manipulation? JavaScript has not comfortable date functions like php or java witch included filters. If you want this you have to write the function by yourself of use a predefined JS Library like Moment JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the offset to the time like :

```
var datetime = new Date();
datetime.setTime( datetime.getTime() + datetime.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );
```

And you can parse datetime instance to exclude gmt offset.

Comment: For extended time manipulations, check out the moment.js library.